# Expressions stop evaluating after changing web.xml version from 2.4 to 3

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, jstl

If I am using following in `web.xml`

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

then following CSS file is loading

`<link href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

but if I change `web.xml` to following

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
```

CSS file is not loading its shows it like:

`404 Not Found - http://localhost:8084/SocialBizz/$%7BpageContext.servletContext.contextPath%7D/resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

Why? do i need some more changes for switching to `3.0`. I am using `tomcat7.0`
another question what version of `JSTL` should I use for `Servlet3.0`

Comment: Is it JSP or JSF page you are using to load CSS file?